# Query params from service A parsed into unexpected object structure in service B and unsure why it is happening

Tags: node.js, laravel, typescript, nestjs, query-string

Problem: Encountered a really weird bug when our **service A** (laravel php) calls an endpoint by **service B** (nodejs typescript + ajv + nestjs).
Let me explain it further below.

Example code in **service A** for building the query parameters

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
$queryParams = http_build_query(['ids' => $ids]);
dump($queryParams) 
// ids%5B0%5D=1&ids%5B1%5D=2&ids%5B2%5D=3
// b.com/bar?ids[0]=1&ids[1]=2&ids[2]=3
```

In **service B**, the expected received query params should be

```
{ ids: [1,2,3] }
```

It worked all well in dev, code deployed to production, then we started seeing validation errors from **SOME of the requests** because the query params is now

```
{ 
 ids: {
  '0' : '1',
  '1' : '2',
  '2' : '3'
 }
}
```

We are pretty sure latest code is deployed to all instances so that rules out possibility of code difference in **service A** causing the difference in query params sent.

Spent 1 whole day trying to trace the root cause but still no answers at the moment.

**Question:** What format could the query parameters be sent in in order for it to be parsed into the object structure above?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is due to nestjs @Query decorator (which uses Express under the hood) being unable to parse the query params correctly into expected array if length of params is above 21.

e.g

Query array with 21 elements

```
ids[0]=160431133&amp;ids[1]=16048883&amp;ids[2]=16048882&amp;ids[3]=16041333&amp;ids[4]=16041313&amp;ids[5]=16041303&amp;ids[6]=16041293&amp;ids[7]=16041283&amp;ids[8]=16041273&amp;ids[9]=16041263&amp;ids[10]=16041253&amp;ids[11]=16041243&amp;ids[12]=16041233&amp;ids[13]=16041133&amp;ids[14]=19116791&amp;ids[15]=19116691&amp;ids[16]=19116591&amp;ids[17]=19116590&amp;ids[18]=19116581&amp;ids[19]=19116571&amp;ids[20]=12416591&amp;
```

Parsed as

```
['160431133', ...., '12416591']
```

Query array with more than 21 elements

```
ids[0]=160431133&amp;ids[1]=16048883&amp;ids[2]=16048882&amp;ids[3]=16041333&amp;ids[4]=16041313&amp;ids[5]=16041303&amp;ids[6]=16041293&amp;ids[7]=16041283&amp;ids[8]=16041273&amp;ids[9]=16041263&amp;ids[10]=16041253&amp;ids[11]=16041243&amp;ids[12]=16041233&amp;ids[13]=16041133&amp;ids[14]=19116791&amp;ids[15]=19116691&amp;ids[16]=19116591&amp;ids[17]=19116590&amp;ids[18]=19116581&amp;ids[19]=19116571&amp;ids[20]=12416591&amp;ids[21]=123456789
```

Parsed as

```
{
'0': 160431133
.
.
.
'21': 123456789
}
```